# How to get number of rows in group after GROUP BY select in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, group-by

Let MySQL `table` example

```
id | grp | title
1  | 1   | Item1
2  | 1   | Item2
3  | 2   | Item3
```

After sql `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY grp` we have result:

```
id | grp | title
1  | 1   | Item1
3  | 2   | Item3
```

How can I get number of rows in group? Like this:

```
id | grp | title | grp_count
1  | 1   | Item1 | 2
3  | 2   | Item3 | 1
```

And if it possible, I want to do it by Doctrine2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If selecting the id and title does not matter in other words it will select any of id and title while doing group by  you can use the following

```
select
id,
grp,
title,
count(*) as  grp_count
from table
GROUP BY grp
```

Comment: Thanks. It works in raw Mysql, but don't works in Doctrine2. grp_count always returns 1. Maybe you know why?

`$this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(e.chain) as chain_cnt')
    ->andWhere('e.active = 1')
    ->addGroupBy('e.chain');`

Comment: How about adding `addSelect('e.chain,COUNT(*) as chain_cnt')` and may be you have only one count for the condition `e.active = 1` ?

Comment: I feel I found solution. It doesn't works because of use of LIMIT/OFFSET. Without limits it works fine.

Comment: Not because of limits. It didn't works because of `fetchJoinCollection = true` in Doctrine Paginator. If it set to false, all works fine.

Comment: I see ok, I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) titlesNumber
FROM myTable
GROUP BY grp
```

[DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f55b8/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY column_name);
```